# How to code a button that permits only one click per user per day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, cookies

In this site: theanimalrescuesite.com there is a button which can be clicked once a day. So my question is how to make a similiar button (i don't mean like design) on my site. Whenever there is a person on my site if he clicked earlier to show him an ad for example of if he didn't clicked to show him the button. Does anybody have an idea how to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Beyond coding the button**
First you need to understand that this requires some work on the backend, with just JavaScript on the browser the solutions you implements will be easily tempered with by just removing cookies or changing the JavaScript code:

These are some options for starters:

1. Using cookies: You simply add a cookie to the browser when the user first clicks on the button, then check if the cookie exists to disable the button.
   **This solution is inefficient, reason: simply delete cookies and enjoy infinite clicks.**
2. Using sessions: You initiate a user session on your backend, if clicking the button requires a registration, then you simply make a session with the user data available on your database, you set a field on your user model that indicates if the user already clicked for today or not, then you disable/enable the button based on that value in your user model.
   You also need to make a check on your clicks,
   you check the status of the user that sent the click, this is
   because people can tamper with JavaScript on your browser and send
   you clicks even if you disable the button.
   **This solution (based on my humble opinion) is optimal as it takes everything (again from what i know) into consideration.**

Now if the users don't need to register, you simply make a session with the user's IP address as an identifier.

There might be simpler ways to do it, but I don't know any :D

**Now if you don't care about click counts per user or unique clicks, then you don't need to do all the work above.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't have a user system. I don't only need to disable the button I need to hide it and to place an ad where the button stands.

Comment: if you don't care about click counts per user or unique clicks in general, then you don't need a user system.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cookie once the user click the button which will expired in one day so accord to the cookie you can find where the user clicked the button or not then you can enable or disable the button.

**To set cookie**

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var date, expires;
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

**To read cookie**

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aravind Sivam beat me to it. [I did it in jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/L1Lykrxj/). Two examples, one will disable the button for one day after click, the other will hide it. (Note that a user can easily by-pass this by disabling JavaScript.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(".example-1")) {
            $.cookie("button1", 1, {
                expires: 1
            });
            $this.prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $.cookie("button2", 1, {
                expires: 1
            });
            $this.hide();
        }
    });

    if ($.cookie("button1")) {
        $(".example-1").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    if ($.cookie("button2")) {
        $(".example-2").hide();
    }
});
```